# Something wrong with my XML?

Tags: extjs, xml-parsing

i'm parsing an xml with my extjs but it returns only one of the five components.

only the first one of the five components.

```
Ext.regModel('Card', {
    fields: ['investor']    
});

var store = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'Card',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'xmlformat.xml',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'investors'
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        single: true,
        datachanged: function(){
            Ext.getBody().unmask();
            var items = [];
            store.each(function(rec){
                                        alert(rec.get('investor'));

            });
```

and my xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<investors>
    <investor>Active</investor>
    <investor>Aggressive</investor>
    <investor>Conservative</investor>
    <investor>Day Trader</investor>
    <investor>Very Active</investor>
</investors>    
<events>
    <event>3 Month Expiry</event>
    <event>LEAPS</event>
    <event>Monthlies</event>
    <event>Monthly Expiries</event>
    <event>Weeklies</event>
</events>
<prices>
    <price>$0.5</price>
    <price>$0.05</price>
    <price>$1</price>
    <price>$22</price>
    <price>$100.34</price>
</prices>   
</root>
```

wen i run the code only "Active" comes out. . . .

i know that i'm doing something wrong but i'm not sure what....

please help . . . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every thing was fine execpt that my xml format should be like this:

Active
    3 Month Expiry
    $0.5


    Aggressive
    LEAPS
    $0.05


    Conservative
    Monthlies
    $1


    Day Trader
    Monthly Expiries
    $22


    Very Active
    Weeklies
    $100.34

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>
<root>
    <investor>Active</investor>
    <event>3 Month Expiry</event>
    <price>$0.5</price>
</root>
<root>
    <investor>Aggressive</investor>
    <event>LEAPS</event>
    <price>$0.05</price>
</root>
<root>
    <investor>Conservative</investor>
    <event>Monthlies</event>
    <price>$1</price>
</root>
<root>
    <investor>Day Trader</investor>
    <event>Monthly Expiries</event>
    <price>$22</price>
</root>
<root>
    <investor>Very Active</investor>
    <event>Weeklies</event>
    <price>$100.34</price>
</root>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to visit the sencha.com tutorial on how to use XML with a grid.
[XML Grid Sample](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/xml-grid.html)

You should take not of how to properly structure your XML so that it can be consumed by a data store.

Answer (score 0):

The Ext XML grid needs to be configured to look for the repeating elements to map to each record in your store/grid.  You had it configured for `investors`, of which there is only 1. Then you mapped a field for `investor` and it is just grabbing the first one that it encounters for the "column" of that "row".

The repeating element for your "rows" in the grid should be `investor`, not `investors`.

Change: `record: 'investors'`
to: `record: 'investor'`