# Read nested XML to model with hasMany association, Sencha, ExtJS

Tags: xml-parsing, extjs4, sencha-touch-2, model-associations

I am trying to parse the following xml (after hosting in my local machine) and load it to store.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
    <user>
       <id>2</id>
       <name>shameel</name>
       <post>
         <user_id>5</user_id>
         <title>programmer</title>
         <body>nothing</body>
       </post>
       <post>
         <user_id>6</user_id>
         <title>newpost</title>
         <body>congrats</body>
       </post>
    </user> 
<user>
       <id>3</id>
       <name>abdulls</name>
       <post>
         <user_id>5</user_id>
         <title>programmer1</title>
         <body>nothing1</body>
       </post>
       <post>
         <user_id>6</user_id>
         <title>newpost1</title>
         <body>congrats1</body>
       </post>
       <post>
         <user_id>7</user_id>
         <title>newpost1</title>
         <body>congrats1</body>
       </post>
    </user>       
</users>
```

The models used are as follows:

```
Ext.define("SectionModel", {
            extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
            config : {
                fields : [{
                            name : 'section',
                            type : 'string',
                            mapping : '@section'
                        }],
                proxy : {
                    type : 'ajax', 

                     url : 'http://localhost:8080/sample1.xml', //sample1.xml is the file

                    reader : {
                        type : 'xml',
                        rootProperty : 'configs',
                        record : 'navigation'
                    }
                },

                hasMany : [{
                    model : 'ArticlesModel',
                    name : 'articlesModel',
                         associationKey:'sections'

                    }]



            }
        });










Ext.define("ArticlesModel", {
            extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
            config : {
                fields : [{
                        name : 'title',
                        type : 'string',
                        mapping : '@title'
                    }, {
                        name : 'value',
                        type : 'string',
                        mapping : '@value'
                    }],

                    proxy : {
                    type : 'ajax',
                                        url : 'http://localhost:8080/sample1.xml', //sample1.xml is the file
                    reader : {
                        type : 'xml',
                        rootProperty : 'navigation',
                        record : 'section'
                    }
                },

                belongsTo : 'SectionModel'


            }
        });
```

Store used as below:

```
Ext.define("SectionStore", {
            extend : 'Ext.data.Store',

            config : {
                model : 'SectionModel',
                autoLoad : 'true'



            }
        });
```

I try to access the content as below:

```
var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.get('SectionStore');
        if (!store) {
            console.log("Store not found");
            return;
        }

store.load(function(records, operation, success) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < store.getCount(); i++) {
                        var section_title = store.getAt(i).get('section');
                                                var subsection_val = store.getAt(i).articlesModel().get('title');//this function fails saying no "get" function for the object
}
});
```

Here I am able to obtain section_title. But cannot get subsection_val. I ve tried this with the proxy in store, but could not fix it. Can any one please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into similar issues with parsing nested XML elements. Unfortunately, after much hacking around in the XML Parsing code, I eventually gave up. (Ended up writing a passthrough to our web services that would transform the response in to JSON)

You can read about my (mis)-adventures here:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?189537-Sencha-Touch-2.0-nested-XML-parsing

Comment: Yes json is the option. XML some how creates issues. We encapsulated XML in a jsonp and obtained it.