# Sencha Touch 2, nested XML parsing nodeValue

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Im using a nested XML and parsing it using 'hasMany'.. I would appreciate if someone could tell me how to read the value of the node '<**type**>'. I can easily read the attributes 'id' & 'val' of '' using mapping but i want to also read the node value eg. 257411 in
<**type** id="3" val="0">257411
I would appreciate if anyone could provide a suitable 'mapping'

XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<basics id="744" name="social">
      <number>302221</number>
      <types>
             <type id="3" val="0">257411</type>
             <type id="2" val="1081337">28213</type>
             <type id="1" val="263258">8645</type>
             <type id="5" val="0">3664</type>
             <type id="4" val="0">2246</type>
             <type id="9" val="0">1124</type>
            <type id="10" val="0">918</type>
      </types>
</basics>
```

model **Basic**
Ext.define("ap3.model.Basic",{
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",

```
config: {
    fields: [
             {name: 'id', mapping: '@id'},
             {name: 'name', mapping: '@name'},

             {name: 'number', mapping: 'number'}
             ],


             associations: [
                {
                    type: 'hasMany',
                    model: 'apv3.model.Type',
                    associationKey: 'types'
                }]
}
```

});

model **Type**
Ext.define("ap3.model.Type",{
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",

```
config: {
    fields: [
             {name: 'id', mapping: '@id'},
             {name: 'val', mapping: '@val'},
             {name: 'type', mapping: 'type'}

             ],

             proxy: {
         type: 'memory',
         reader: {
                type: 'xml',
                record: 'type'
            }
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

"mapping" accepts a function too:

```
{name: 'id', mapping: '@id'},
{name: 'name', mapping: '@name'},
{name: 'number', mapping:  function (node) {
    return (node.firstChild ? node.firstChild.nodeValue : null);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if that counts as an answer, but having spent a lot of time on the same issue I'd say this is a bug in the framework :(

A couple of relevant links:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11549596/454266
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?209025-Nested-XML-reader-problem&p=838952&viewfull=1#post838952

Luckily nested JSON works fine. My advice is to switch to it or to handle loading of the lower-level models manually (e.g. writing your own method doing the job of hasMany association by creating a store / reader and feeding this.raw.types to it).