# Sencha Architect XML TreeStore fails to load/map XML

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I'm trying to use XML TreeStore in Sencha Architect and it fails to load any data from the given XML. While I can access that store as an object, its `getCount()` returns 'undefined' and methods like `getNodeById('foobar')` result in 'cannot read property 'foobar' of undefined' which makes me think the mapping doesn't happen (store is initialised but failed to parse the data / instantiate models).

The same XML with the same model but accessed via a flat store in the same basic setup works fine (e.g. `getCount()` returns 2 as expected). Tree store with a JSON version of data again works fine as well.

The class for my problematic store by Sencha Architect is:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.DocumentStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.Document'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            autoLoad: true,
            storeId: 'TreeDocumentStore',
            model: 'MyApp.model.Document',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'DocumentTemplates.xml',
                reader: {
                    type: 'xml',
                    root: 'Templates',
                    record: 'Template'
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

The source XML file store refers to is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Templates>
  <Template>
    <Id>A253338C-CDFA-4182-9E1C-652EAAB713F8</Id>
    <Title>Template 1</Title>
    <Children />
  </Template>
  <Template>
    <Id>26D5B83C-7E9E-49E2-B174-F9A6C7BA07A8</Id>
    <Title>Template 2</Title>
    <Children />
  </Template>
</Templates>
```

In case I have misunderstood the purpose of 'root' property I tried different node names for global root and supposed child node roots setting 'root' property of the reader to all the possible values, but no luck.

I tried to remove empty  from the  nodes as well, same effect.

This is not about displaying items from the store in a view yet, I'm only trying to access the data in controller.

P.S. Dummy project with an XML file, tree store and controller accessing that store in `onLaunch` is here: http://sdrv.ms/RAsj26

Comment: Might be useful - I added '<total>2</total>' under <Templates> root and called store.getTotalCount() - unlike getCount() which returns 'undefined' this method doesn't exist. So the store didn't initialise at all?

Comment: Okay, getCount() doesn't work because it is not applicable to tree stores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having spent some time with this issue my own answer to a similar question is probably relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12886943/454266

Looks like tree structures for XML sources are not supported properly in the current version of framework, be it TreeStore or association mechanisms.