# sencha touch 2:how to read value of the record node in xml file

Tags: xml, sencha-touch-2, nodevalue

Before ask question,I found there is a similar question:[Sencha Touch 2, nested XML parsing nodeValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176719/sencha-touch-2-nested-xml-parsing-nodevalue)
I use model/proxy to load data form xml file,almost succesed but there is a problem that I can't read the value of the record node in xml file.
my xml file likes this:
myRecord.js

コード:

```
<records>
    <record attribute='a' id='1'>A</record>
    <record attribute='b' id='2'>B</record>
    <record attribute='c' id='3'>C</record>
</record>
```

my model likes this:

コード:

```
Ext.define('RecordModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
         fields: [
             {name: 'recoreAttr', mapping: '@attribute', type:'string'}
             {name: 'recordId', mapping: '@id', type:'string'}
             {name: 'recordName', mapping: 'record', type:'string'}
          ],
         proxy: {
             type:'ajax',
             url: 'myRecord.js'
             reader: {
                  type:'xml';
                  rootProperty:'records'
                  record:'record',           // only occurs for the node configed here
             }
         }
    }
})
```

then I create a Store of 'RecordModel' and call the load() method, I found the attribute(a,b,c in my xml file) and id(1,2,3 in my xml file) was correctly read. but the value(A,B,C in my xml file) between   was not read. I thought it must be my mapping format is wrong,but I don,t know what correct mapping format likes.
this problem only occurs to the node configed as the 'record' in the proxy,if thre are nested node in the record node,the value can be read successfully.

```
<records>
    <record attribute='a' id='1'>A</record>
    <record attribute='b' id='2'>B</record>
    <record attribute='c' id='3'>C</record>
    <record attribute='c' id='3'>
        <nested>D</nested>
    </record>
</record>
```

the nested node value 'D' can read.